# SSRS Expressions Not Executed When Rows Are Hidden

Tags: reporting-services, visibility, hidden, ssrs-expression, custom-code

I'm new to SSRS and have been tasked with converting our Crystal Reports to it. The problem I'm running into is when trying to hide the detail rows which contain the data for the group calculations, the expressions no longer get calculated. How can I hide the detail data, but still execute the expressions in those rows so that the group summaries are accurate?

Values before setting row visibility to hide -

[image]

Values after setting row visibility to hide -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack, but you could set the font color of the detail rows to white and make the rows as small as possible instead of hiding them... If someone else has a better suggestion, I'm interested as well!